# Is Windows Azure update all my websites at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created some websites and deloped to Windows Azure. When I deploy one of them to Windows Azure, **I saw all websites are updated at that time** in **Management Service -> Operation Logs**. That's strange for me because I want the others should be run stablly, not related to the website I was deploying. Could anyone explain?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: How did you deploy your site? (webdeploy/ftp/git/...)

Comment: @AmitApple I deploy by: Right click on project -> Publish

Comment: Check the files on all your sites, I'm sure only the one you deployed has the changes